# Android context menu displayed in onCreate

Tags: android, xml, contextmenu

I'm trying to add the functionality that if the user clicks a button in my mainActivity, it starts another Activity and it has to pop up a menu with two possibilities on the screen. When the users picks either possibility, a different XML from the net will be loaded in my lay-out.

I don't know if this is possible to access a context menu in the onCreate method or if there's another way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Pop open an AlertDialog with a list of items you want to show. Fire a startActivity(intent) when your choice of item is selected.

Sample code here:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#AddingAList

Comment: I've formulated my question a bit wrong, with XML I didn't mean my lay-out XML but an XML with data from the internet that will be loaded in my lay-out. Would it still work te same way?

Comment: You can insert XML fetching code within the OnClickListener method mentioned in the code I posted. Ideally, I would pop up a 'loading' dialog after an item was selected while fetching the XML. Dismiss the loading dialog when you've updated your layout with the XML.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you display a dialog with the two options before loading your new Activity? And then, according the user's selection display the corresponding xml?

I would do it this way:

1. You have your mainActivity running
2. When the user clicks your button, you show an AlertDialog with the "positive" button representing the first xml file and the "negative" button representing your second xml.
3. Upon click on any of the buttons, you show your second Activity by using different Intent-actions and checking which intent was used in the `onCreate` method of your second Activity.

For your button:

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            DialogInterface.OnClickListener listener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    Intent act2 = null;
                    switch (which) {
                    case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                        // layout 1
                        act2 = new Intent("package.example.act2_layout1");
                        startActivity(act2);
                        break;
                    case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                        act2 = new Intent("package.example.act2_layout2");
                        startActivity(act2);
                    }
                }
            };

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mainActivity.this);
            builder.setTitle("Make your choice")
                .setPositiveButton("Layout 1", listener)
                .setNegativeButton("Layout 2", listener);
        }
    });
```

And then in the `onCreate` method:

```
Intent starter = getIntent();
    if (starter.getAction().equals("package.example.act2_layout1")) {
        // use layout 1
    } else if (starter.getAction().equals("package.example.act2_layout2")) {
        // use layout 2
    }
```